# Adding HTTP headers to webpack bundle requests

Tags: webpack, http-headers, jwt

I am creating a SPA with Webpack 2 and code splitting. Some bundles will be admin-only and thus will require authentication and authorization. I'm using JWT and I plan to have the token on localStorage.

How can I add the authentication header to webpack bundle requests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look through the Webpack code, you'll see bundles are loaded via `<script>` tags, as follows:

```
...
/******/        // start chunk loading
/******/        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
/******/        var script = document.createElement('script');
/******/        script.type = 'text/javascript';
/******/        script.charset = 'utf-8';
/******/        script.async = true;
/******/        script.timeout = 120000;
/******/
/******/        if (__webpack_require__.nc) {
/******/            script.setAttribute("nonce", __webpack_require__.nc);
/******/        }
/******/        script.src = __webpack_require__.p + "" + chunkId + ".js";
...
```

So there isn't a way to add headers to this unfortunately.

Any chance you could pass your token using a cookie? That at least would be shared.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. I can use cookies but I wanted to use only one auth method... I guess I'll need both.